# Google API PHP - OAuth Issue - "Request had invalid authentication credentials"

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I am I am trying to get Google's API PHP client working with OAuth so that I can access Analytics and Search Console Data. I have been following the [example here from Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php). I get sent to Google to sign in and authorise access, then when I am redirected back to the site, I get a 401 error "Request had invalid authentication credentials".

N.B. I am using the [Google API PHP Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

I have been looking for hours now and can't get this to work correctly. Here is my code.

In index.php:

```
<?php
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('../../public/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
$client->setApplicationName("Tool");
$client->setAccessType("offline");


// If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
// else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  // Set the access token on the client.
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

  // Create an authorized analytics service object.
  $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

  var_dump($_SESSION);

  // Call the Analytics Reporting API V4.
  $response = getReport($analytics);

  // Print the response.
  printResults($response);

} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}


function getReport($analytics) {

  // Replace with your view ID. E.g., XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "XXXXXXXX";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}

function printResults($reports) {
  for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) {
    $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
    $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
    $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
    $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
    $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();

    for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
      $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
      $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
      $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
        print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
      }

      for ($j = 0; $j < count( $metricHeaders ) && $j < count( $metrics ); $j++) {
        $entry = $metricHeaders[$j];
        $values = $metrics[$j];
        print("Metric type: " . $entry->getType() . "\n" );
        for ( $valueIndex = 0; $valueIndex < count( $values->getValues() ); $valueIndex++ ) {
          $value = $values->getValues()[ $valueIndex ];
          print($entry->getName() . ": " . $value . "\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is in oauth2callback.php:

```
<?php
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Create the client object and set the authorization configuration
// from the client_secrets.json you downloaded from the Developers Console.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('../../public/client_secrets.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
$client->setApplicationName("Tool");
$client->setAccessType("offline");

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/tests/simple-file-upload.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying this out directly from the code, use a REST client to send and receive the request and response.  Once that is successful, use those parameters in your code.